# Xcode: как убрать source control из проекта и удалить всю историю?

Tags: git, xcode, ide, svn, контроль-версий

Какое-то время я использовать систему контроля версий, встроенную в Xcode, но теперь я решил ей не пользоваться. Какие есть способы отключения системы контроля версий в Xcode IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Способ 1

*Просто отключаем управление версиями для всех проектов.*

Заходим в нужный проект Xcode, в меню выбираем **Xcode-> Preferences**, затем **Source Control** и отключаем **Enable Source Control**.

[image]

---

## Способ 2

*Отключаем конкретный репозиторий для всех проектов.*

Заходим в **Xcode-> Preferences-> Accounts-> Repositories** и удаляем ненужные репозитории.

[image]

---

## Способ 3

*Отключаем управление версиями для конкретного проекта и удаляем всю его историю.*

Сначала закрываем нужный проект. Затем нам понадобится включить отображение скрытых файлов и папок. Это можно сделать через **Terminal**:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE;killall Finder
```

После этого идём в директорию проекта и удаляем все файлы/папки с названиями `.svn`, `.git` или `.tf` (в зависимости от системы контроля версий). При следующем открытии проекта Xcode автоматически будет работать в стандартном режиме без контроля версий.

Пример директории с **svn**:

[image]

---

<sub>Перевод [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21198575/5308802).</sub>